# Facebook Graph API, definitive list of extended permissions

Tags: permissions, facebook-graph-api

Can someone point me to an up-to-date and exhaustive list of extended permissions for Facebook Graph API?  I've been using (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), but that list doesn't include music, books, etc.  Is that a subset of one of the existing permissions?

Comment: Hi Mark, Did you get the best answer for your question and if true, please share me. Many thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4

This should help you with all the permissions for music, news, video and activity :)

Comment: just scroll down more :/

Answer (score 1):

ads_management,ads_read,bookmarked,email,manage_notifications,manage_pages,publish_actions,publish_pages,read_insights,read_mailbox,read_page_mailboxes,read_stream,rsvp_event,tab_added,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_events,user_friends,user_games_activity,user_groups,user_hometown,user_likes,user_location,user_managed_groups,user_photos,user_posts,user_relationship_details,user_relationships,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_tagged_places,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history

As you can see at:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions

Answer (score 0):

With newest version I found [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference) is helpful for me.

Answer (score -1):

That is the definitive list, I believe those elements are subsets and probably depend on the permissions given to you by the user. See this post: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=283691

Comment: Ha ha, that my post over on the FB forums.  :-)  For those interested in the answer: books, music, etc. are included in "user_likes" permission.  I'm not sure how I missed that initially.